# What post-hoc test can be used on data with missing values?

Tags: missing-data, post-hoc

I have run 13 data-stream classification approaches on 8 different datasets, giving a 8x13 result table. I was hoping to use the Friedman test to test for a significant difference between the approaches. However one of the approaches can not be used on two of the datasets so there are two missing values in my result table.

I have read that the Skillings-Mack statistic can be used when there a missing values so I used the Matlab implementation I found at: http://www.geog.ucsb.edu/~pingel/code/mackskill/skillmack.html which gave a T value of 48.58 and a p-value < 0.0001.

My question is in regards to post-hoc tests. Are there any recommended post-hoc tests for data with missing values or can any of the usual post-hoc test be used?

Comment: It rather looks like Matlab, not R code :)

Comment: :) Oh yeah, sorry I mean Matlab. I've changed the original post now.

Comment: Or you can try using pairwise Wilcoxon's signed rank test preferably with the Bonferroni-Holm p-value adjustment method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can still use the Bonferroni–Dunn test as per Friedman post hoc test. At least this is what Silva & Zhao (2012) did in their paper "Network-Based Stochastic Semisupervised Learning".

regards,
Ken.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be the Nemenyi test. Again, you'd apply it as you would for a Friedman post-hoc test (for example, see *[Statistical Comparisons of Classifiersover Multiple Data Sets (Demsar 2006)](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume7/demsar06a/demsar06a.pdf)*).